# regex to extract string part

Tags: php, regex

i have this string :

> Le serveur a retourné une erreur "500 An exception occurred while executing 'select     DIVISIONTEST(4,0) from dual': SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20000 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-20000: Bien essayé! ORA-06512: à "FOO.DIVISIONTEST", line 8 (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:148)".

i would like to show only this part : `Bien essayé!` nothing before or after this part.

This string is generated by a:

```
$exception->getMessage()
```

Can you help me with a regex ? 
thanks you

EDIT : sorry , the customized message will change. I should have been more precise. I'm looking for a way to get the message after `ORA-20000:` and before the `ORA:` following .
I'm trying to get exception raised from a PL/SQL request. The error raised is a customized message

Comment: Thanks kevinabelita, you edited my post 5 secs before me

Comment: is the word `Bien essayé!` would change later?

Comment: Pretty hard to come up with a valid Regex with only a single instance of a possible exception string being supplied. Can you give us more examples of what kind of exceptions you need to extract messages from?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: updated after original post changed:

```
$re = '/OCIStmtExecute: ORA-[0-9]+: (.+) ORA-[0-9]+:/'; 
$subject = $exception->getMessage();

preg_match($re, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Ah thanks, i tested it and i've got `Warning: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`
edit : it needed backslash. But my array is empty. I keep trying thanks

Comment: Sorry, forgot the delimiter. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

Well since you only want to match one case, you could use: `preg_match`
See PHP Manual: https://www.php.net/preg_match

Example:

```
$subject = $exception->getMessage();
$pattern = '/Bien essayé!/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
if (preg_match("/Bien essayé!/i",$exception->getMessage())
   echo : "Bien essayé!";
else
   echo "Pas bien essayé :-D ";
?>
```